Where are extension files?
In the manual some files are mentioned like this one

You can find a portable implementation of this extended case in
compat/caseext.fs.

Where can I find this file? I searched my computer but could not find it.
I'm trying to use the case as mentioned on that page:
case
  condition1 ?of exit-code1 endof
  condition2 ?of exit-code2 endof
  condition3 ?of exit-code3 endof
  ...
next-case
common code afterwards

EDIT
As per comment by @DarkBee I'm adding the error:
: sgn ( n -- -1|0|1 )  compiled
( n ) case  compiled
dup 0 < ?of drop -1 endof 
:13: Undefined word
dup 0 < >>>?of<<< drop -1 endof
Backtrace:
$107049A20 throw 
$10705FC48 no.extensions 
$10704D358 compiler-notfound1 

The word ?of is defined in a file called compat/caseext.fs as mentioned in the manual. If it is off topic to ask here where this file is, then there is nothing to do but close the question. So be it.

Please [edit] your question to specifically and clearly define the problem that you are trying to solve. Additional details — including all relevant code, error messages, and debugging logs — will help readers to better understand your problem and [what you are asking].

FYI: If the actual question actually is "where to find/download these files", then the question is off-topic here on StackOverflow

@DarkBee I installed the bleeding edge from here https://gforth.org/ and now I have the compat directory and the extension files. Do you think it's better to close the question?
